# How to position a element (drop down menu item) exactly below the parent menu

Tags: php, .net, html, css

I am trying to place a dropdown menu item below the parent menu. When u hover on the parent menu, the child dropdown menu item's visibility will turn visible.

I positioned the child elements using position:absolute and using top and left.

But when i change the resolution of the monitor the left and top alignment changes

How to position that element. Plz help any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does the parent have a `position:relative` ?

Comment: No it dont have postion:relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) has a wonderful, if old, [article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns) on all the intricacies of css drop down menus, with just a little javascript to fix IE. I believe all the CSS still works great, but I can't speak to the JS still being relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the menu and submenu to a parent div element and just hide/show the submenu when needed:

```
<div id="container>
<div id="menu_item">This is a menu item</div>
<ul id="submenu">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The css:

```
#submenu { display: none; }
#menu_item:hover + #submenu { display: block; }
```

Please note that the CSS won't work in IE, you will need to use JS to display the submenu.

Comment: with your html you could do `#container:hover #submenu { display:block; }` which *is* IE compatible

Comment: It is not IE compatible as older IEs do not support hover on any element other than <a>.